# How to make this query work?

Tags: mysql

Hello i have the following query:

```
SELECT
    cmfilm.*,
    cmgenre.titel AS genretitel,
    cmvertoning.*,
    cmzaal.titel AS zaaltitel
FROM 
    cmfilm 
  LEFT JOIN cmvertoning ON cmvertoning.film_id=cmfilm.id 
  LEFT JOIN cmgenre ON cmfilm.genre_id=cmgenre.id
  LEFT JOIN cmzaal ON cmvertoning.zaal_id=cmzaal.id 
GROUP BY 
    cmfilm.titel 
SORT BY 
    cmgenre.titel ASC
```

this doesnt seem to work, there is a problem with the sorting part, anyone know where the problem is?

Comment: @Martin Liversage Ah, simultaneous edit. Sorry.

Comment: the error is: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SORT BY cmgenre.titel ASC' at line 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to sort the result then shouldn't you be using ORDER BY?

Like this;

```
SELECT cmfilm.*, cmgenre.titel AS genretitel, cmvertoning.*, cmzaal.titel AS zaaltitel FROM cmfilm LEFT JOIN cmvertoning ON cmvertoning.film_id=cmfilm.id LEFT JOIN cmgenre ON cmfilm.genre_id=cmgenre.id LEFT JOIN cmzaal ON cmvertoning.zaal_id=cmzaal.id GROUP BY cmfilm.titel ORDER BY cmgenre.titel ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL you need to group by ALL the non-aggregate columns you are selecting to get predictable results. Just because MySQL does not give you an error, doesn't make it right.

You seem to have `cmfilm.titel` in your `group by` clause, but you have no aggregate functions (sum/count etc.) , so as it is now, you probably should drop that `group by` , or tell us more about what you actually want to query.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should by ORDER BY in stead of SORT BY:

```
SELECT cmfilm.*, cmgenre.titel AS genretitel, cmvertoning.*, cmzaal.titel AS zaaltitel
FROM cmfilm
     LEFT JOIN cmvertoning ON cmvertoning.film_id=cmfilm.id
     LEFT JOIN cmgenre ON cmfilm.genre_id=cmgenre.id
     LEFT JOIN cmzaal ON cmvertoning.zaal_id=cmzaal.id
GROUP BY cmfilm.titel
ORDER BY cmgenre.titel:
```

If that is not the problem, please include the error message.